# 1001x error with biztalk in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, biztalk

My solution and projects were all running fine. I ran another build and ended up with 39 errors, all related to a particular orchestration in my biztalk. All the errors are cannot find symbol, illegal statements,  and invalid identifiers.

I'm tried cleaning and building, and rebuilding, but the error doesnt seem to go away. My first error is 212 unknown system exception, where in my error log is telling me 1001x error.

edit: I also do not seeing any exclamation points on my actual orchestration

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things you can try:

1. in %Project%\obj\Debug\BizTalk\XLang you should See File0.cs.  Delete this, clean and Rebuild.
2. Make a very minor modification to the Orchestration, such as add a comment in an Expression Shape.  Clean and Rebuild.
3. Apply the latest CU for your version of BizTalk Server.
4. Set the Build Action of the Orchestration to None.  Build.  Reset to BtsCompile and Rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Actually - all you have to do is open an expression and add a space, anywhere. Anything to cause the file to differ from before. Somehow this forces VS to get out of the broken state its in.